# AfxPumpMessage() is using for?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a main thread and sub thread.
In subthread I sendmessage to main thread.
In main thread, I call this:

```
while( ::WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 0) == WAIT_TIMEOUT )
{
 MSG    message;
 while( ::PeekMessage( &message, NULL , WM_MIN, WM_MAX, PM_NOREMOVE ) )
 {
::AfxPumpMessage();
 }
}
```

It works fine!. But I dont know How does AfxPumpMessage() work? How to it avoid deadlock?
Anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is an appalling busy message loop. Use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` instead. As for `AfxPumpMessage`, what is it? I cannot find official docs for it. Why did you decide to call it? And why did you write `WM_MIN` and `WM_MAX`?

Comment: WM_MIN and WM_MAX is my define. And, if I did not calling AfxPumpMessage(), it will be deadlock. But I dont know how does AfxPumpMessage() work. Do you help me to clear this problem?

Comment: What purpose are `WM_MIN` and `WM_MAX` serving. You only want to deal with a small range of messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code runs a busy loop. The outer `while` loop terminates when the thread is signaled. Until then the loop runs busy and dispatches messages. This is what allows the main thread to wait on the sub-thread, but also respond to the messages that the sub-thread sends.

In fact, the call to `PeekMessage` is rather pointless. It is pointless because `AfxPumpMessage` will do the same, and pump all queued messages.

As I said, your outer loop is a busy loop. You really don't want that. There's no point consuming CPU cycles to do nothing. Instead of `WaitForSingleObject`, you should use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`. This allows you to wait on the thread, and be able to dispatch messages.

Assuming that you don't want to deal with queued messages, and only want to dispatch the sent messages, your loop might look like this:

```
while( ::MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &hThread, FALSE, INFINITE, 
    QS_SENDMESSAGE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1 )
{
    MSG message;
    ::PeekMessage(&message, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);
}
```

This won't deal with an queued messages. If you do need to process those, then the loop would look a little different.

Comment: THanks so much, you mean AfxPumpMessage respond to message from sub thread?

Comment: Yes that is correct. It dispatches incoming sent messages, and pumps the queue.

Comment: I understand, I will try to use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(), thank you for your help.

Comment: I added some code to show how to use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` to block for either an incoming sent message, or the thread being signaled. The trivial `PeekMessage` dispatches any incoming sent messages. I've assumed that you only care about dispatching these incoming sent messages. If you want to deal with queued messages (e.g. input messages) then the code would be a little different.